# Create a smart contract in Marlowe from A to Z

Tags: smart-contract, marlowe

What is the process of building a smart contract in Marlowe from start to deployment and first main net transaction? I know that there's blockly and Marlowe playground. But I can't figure out the step-by-step algo of doing it from the docs.

Here's what I want to build:
Bob deposits 100 iUSD Ann deposits 10 iUSD, if event "1" happens Ann gets 105 iUSD, Tom gets 5 iUSD else if event "2" happens Bob gets 100 iUSD, Tom gets 10 iUSD.

Events will be triggered in the frontend.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Guidance on building a Marlowe contract and running it on `mainnet` is split into two pieces because Marlowe is a blockchain-agnostic language but it is also implemented on Cardano. [Playground](https://docs.marlowe.iohk.io/docs/developer-tools/playground) lets one simulate Marlowe contracts in the abstract while [Runtime](https://docs.marlowe.iohk.io/docs/developer-tools/runtime/marlowe-runtime) lets one execute them concretely on the Cardano blockchain.

1. The [Concepts tutorials](https://docs.marlowe.iohk.io/tutorials/concepts/overview) teach the Marlowe language and walk through examples.
2. The [Guides](https://docs.marlowe.iohk.io/tutorials/guides/overview) exemplify using the [Marlowe Starter Kit](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-starter-kit/blob/runtime%40v0.0.2/ReadMe.md), which is freely available on https://demeter.run/ for use without installing any software.

Regarding your specific example, the [sixth lesson of the starter kit](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-starter-kit/blob/main/06-cip30/ReadMe.md) shows how to build a simple front end for a Marlowe contract.

Comment: I feel more comfortable using VS code on my PC than https://demeter.run/ I hope that doesn't break anything. I would be running smart contracts from frontend later anyway.

A very high level question correct me if I'm wrong. Smart-contract building algo looks something like this:

1. Build SC in Blockly.
2. Test SC in Runtime.  
3. Import it into the App bundle 
4. Production build 
5. Deploy optimized bundle to prod server.

Comment: Demeter Run provides convenience, but the starter kit and other examples should work fine if one is using a local Marlowe Runtime or some other service provider.